# Swift: How to declare a static member variable which is a class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to declare a class which has a static variable which I want to set to an object of the class i.e.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

      static var staticSelf:MyViewController
```

This declaration generates the following error:

```
"class var declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier".
```

So I tried several attempts at adding an initialzer but just was getting more or different compilation errors. So instead I tried adding a getter/setter specifier as it says in the error, but this is resulting in an infinite loop when run. I've tried several versions, this is the latest:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

  static var staticSelf:MyViewController {
    set (selfInstance) {
        MyViewController.staticSelf = selfInstance
    }
    get {
        return MyViewController.staticSelf
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyViewController.staticSelf = self
  }
}
```

The initial attempt at the implementation of the setter method was `staticSelf = selfInstance`, XCode flagged this as an error and auto-corrected to `self.staticSelf = selfInstance`, but that results in an infinate loop, so I changed it to `MyViewController.staticSelf = selfInstance`, but that too creates an infinate loop.

I've tried a thousand things to get this set up and could have done it in 3 seconds with objective-C , and am getting very fed up with Swift right now.

Comment: you are assigning `nil` to a non optional

Comment: That's right. you could have done; static var staticSelf:listener? = nil

Comment: @Woofbeans: Don't get fed up with Swift! Once you get the hang of it it's actually great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that in objective-c you would have used a pointer that could be null, in Swift, you do something similar.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    static var staticSelf:MyViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MyViewController.staticSelf = self
    }    

    func somefunc() {
    }
}
```

When you need to access it from elsewhere:

```
if let controller = MyViewController.staticSelf {
    controller.somefunc()
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The basic example

```
class MyClass {
    static var string: String
}
```

does not work because unitialized variables have `nil` value. However, in Swift you can assign `nil` only to optional variables.

You have two options:

1. Declare the variable as optional

   ```
   static var string: String?
   ```

   or

   ```
   static var string: String? = nil
   ```
2. Initialize with a non-nil value:

   ```
   static var string: String = "some value"
   ```

If your aim is to create a singleton, then see the official [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html) for the solution:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    static let staticSelf = MyViewController()
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't a singleton have private initializers?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the value right away in the declaration line:

```
    static var staticSelf = MyViewController()
```

This is, btw. the standard pattern to create a singleton in Swift.